# amazon redshift copy using json having trouble

Tags: amazon-redshift, jsonpath

I have created simple table called as test3

```
create table if not exists test3(

   Studies varchar(300) not null,
   Series varchar(500) not null
   );
```

I got some json data

```
{
        "Studies": [{
                "studyinstanceuid": "2.16.840.1.114151",
                "studydescription": "Some study",
                "studydatetime": "2014-10-03 08:36:00"
        }],
        "Series": [{
                "SeriesKey": "abc",
                "SeriesInstanceUid": "xyz",
                "studyinstanceuid": "2.16.840.1.114151",
                "SeriesDateTime": "2014-10-03 09:05:09"
        }, {
                "SeriesKey": "efg",
                "SeriesInstanceUid": "stw",
                "studyinstanceuid": "2.16.840.1.114151",
                "SeriesDateTime": "0001-01-01 00:00:00"
        }],

        "ExamKey": "exam-key",
}
```

and here is my json_path

```
{

    "jsonpaths": [
        "$['Studies']",
        "$['Series']"
    ]

}
```

Both the json data and json path is uploaded to s3.

I try to execute the following copy command in redshift consule.

```
copy test3
from 's3://mybucket/redshift_demo/input.json'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=my_key;aws_secret_access_key=my_access' 
json 's3://mybucket/redsift_demo/json_path.json'
```

I get the following error. Can anyone please help been stuck on this for sometime now.

```
Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Number of jsonpaths and the number of columns should match. JSONPath size: 1, Number of columns in table or column list: 2
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Number of jsonpaths and the number of columns should match. JSONPath size: 1, Number of columns in table or column list: 2
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     1125432
  location:  s3_utility.cpp:670
  process:   padbmaster [pid=83747]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.
```

Execution time: 1.58s

Comment: The issue with s3 credentials and nothing to do with redshift I was able to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift's error is misleading. The issue is that your input file is wrongly formatted: you have an extra comma after the last JSON entry.

`Copy` succeeds if you change `"ExamKey": "exam-key",` to `"ExamKey": "exam-key"`

Comment: ketan thanks for the comment I found the error, it was my bad I had wrong s3 credentials, basically the s3cmd which was using the upload the files to s3 bucket and s3 credentials in the copy was not matching. Once I fixed that the above error went away.

Comment: but you would still have to remove the extra comma as i suggested. otherwise the `copy` will fail.